# Calculating stderr for a bar plot of rate of events detected

Tags: standard-error

I'm trying to understand the correct way to calculate standard error bars for the plot below.

```
rate:    10 |
events      |     _______
per       5 |     |     |
minute      |_____|     |______
          1 |     |     |     |_____
            |_____|_____|_____|_____|
           0.0   0.25  0.5   0.75  1.0
            measure of detected motion
```

On X we have a measure of motion in a video, looking at each second of video over time, each 1s falls into a range of `[0, 1]` of measured motion. We are counting how many events of a particular type occur relative to the computed motion at that time.

So for Y we have a count of events per minute. It's normalized by time spent observing each bin of motion.

We have 15 total subjects being observed over a long period of time.

**Questions:**

> I'm having trouble figuring out how error bars should be represented
> on data like this. It's not quite a histogram because we normalized
> event count by time.
>
> Also, I'm not sure if I should be using 15 subjects as the denominator
> in stderr calculations, or total events, or total time in a bin.

An example of data would look like:

```
second, bin, event-detected
  1      0        no
  2      0        no
  3      0       yes
...
 100     2        no
 101     2       yes
 102     2        no
```

Comment: Please explain for us what you mean by "standard error bars," because that phrase has several reasonable interpretations in this setting.  One would be standard errors of the individual barplot heights.  Another would view the barplot as summarizing a dataset and the standard error as being the standard error of its mean.  Of greatest importance and usefulness, though, would be a description of why you're doing this: what do you hope these standard errors will represent?

Comment: That's a perfect question. Ultimately what I'm trying to communicate with the error bars is that there is sufficient data underlying the summary plot. As you say there are a number of ways to slice that and much of my question stems from trying to figure out what is most natural to a consumer of the data. I'll have to explain whatever I choose, but it should also make sense visually. My current thinking is that error captures the degree to which we have enough time and enough events to make accurate plots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So for each 1 second interval the endpoint is a number between 0 and 1?  Is the set of possible values discrete, e.g. 0, 0.1, 0.2, ..., 1, or continuous?  Based on your brackets it looks like 0 and 1 are inclusive.  It appears that you are constructing a histogram and if the endpoint is continuous it can be conceptualized as random draws from a beta distribution.   You wouldn't put standard error bars on a histogram, but you could on an empirical cumulative distribution function (ECDF).  Alternatively you could fit a beta model to the data and plot the estimated beta CDF with standard error bars or with tolerance intervals (confidence intervals for population percentiles).

If the endpoint, $Y$, is measured in discrete units, such as multiples of 0.1, you could conceptualize the endpoint $10Y$ as random draws from a binomial distribution.  The options of using a histogram, ECDF, and estimated parametric binomial CDF with standard error bars or tolerance intervals would apply here.

If the raw data involves an endpoint that is bounded on the left by 0 and essentially unbounded on the right this could be conceptualized as random draws from a Poisson or negative binomial distribution (discrete) or a gamma distribution (continuous).